# Detecting edges of an image doesn't work in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection, noise, sobel

I'm working on a script detecting edges of an image.

Here is the script:

```
clear all; close all; clc;

c = rgb2gray(imread('image_S004_I0004.jpg'));
c = double(c);
k = imnoise(c, 'salt & pepper', 0.01); 

gg = [-1 0 1;-2 0 2; -1 0 1];
gh = gg';

grad_g = conv2(k, gg);
grad_h = conv2(k, gh);
grad = sqrt(grad_g.^2 + grad_h.^2);

[r s] = size(grad);
T = 80;
for ii = 1:r
    for jj = 1:s

        if grad(ii, jj) < T
            thresh_grad(ii, jj) = 0;
        else 
            thresh_grad(ii, jj) = 1;
        end
    end
end

figure()
subplot(121); imshow(uint8(c));
subplot(122); imshow(thresh_grad);
```

Here is what I always get:

[image]

On the left is an original image, on the right should be an image with detected edges (as you can see in the script, I have implemented some noise on the image - has to be there). But I get literally nothing, not matter what the value of threshold T is.

Could you please help me to find my mistake?

Comment: didn't look closely but probably`c = double(c);` should be `c = im2double(c);` and at the end `imshow(uint8(c));` should be just `imshow(c);`

Comment: Or do `imshow(thresh_grad,[])`?

Comment: Note that you can replace the loop over all pixels with `thresh_grad = grad >= T`.

Comment: #Sardar Usama
It doesn't work. Still gives me the same result. 

#Cris Luengo
It doesn't work

Comment: @Bacon: Tag people with the `@` character. We don't get notified otherwise. What does `grad` look like? Are you happy with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your code is right before you apply the noise.  You are casting the image to `double` prior to calling `imnoise`.  By doing this, `double` precision images are assumed to have a dynamic range of `[0,1]` and so the output of `imnoise` would be clipped to the `[0,1]` range.  This means that your threshold of `80` would therefore be unsuitable because there will never be any gradient values that would exceed the value of 80 so everything is visualized as black.

In addition, `thresh_grad` is not defined and it's recommended you pre-allocate the image prior to using it.  Simply do `thresh_grad = zeros(size(grad));` prior to the double `for` loop.

As such, call `double` after you make the call to `imnoise` which would make the image still be in `uint8` and then convert to `double` for the purposes of convolution.  By doing this I managed to get output.  I don't have access to your image, but I used the `cameraman.tif` image that's built-into MATLAB's image processing toolbox.

Therefore:

```
c = imread('cameraman.tif');
k = imnoise(c, 'salt & pepper', 0.01); 
k = double(k); % Change

gg = [-1 0 1;-2 0 2; -1 0 1];
gh = gg';

grad_g = conv2(k, gg);
grad_h = conv2(k, gh);
grad = sqrt(grad_g.^2 + grad_h.^2);

[r, s] = size(grad);
thresh_grad = zeros(size(grad)); % Added
T = 80;
for ii = 1:r
    for jj = 1:s

        if grad(ii, jj) < T
            thresh_grad(ii, jj) = 0;
        else 
            thresh_grad(ii, jj) = 1;
        end
    end
end

figure()
subplot(121); imshow(uint8(c));
subplot(122); imshow(thresh_grad);
```

I get:

[image]

---

As for future development, I recommend you use [`im2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html) to actually convert the images to `double` precision, which would also convert the data into a `[0,1]` range.  You would thus need to change the threshold from `80` to `80/255` as the threshold of `80` was originally designed for `uint8` images.

Finally, when you show the original image you can get rid of the `uint8` casting.

For completeness:

```
c = imread('cameraman.tif');
c = im2double(c); % Change
k = imnoise(c, 'salt & pepper', 0.01); 

gg = [-1 0 1;-2 0 2; -1 0 1];
gh = gg';

grad_g = conv2(k, gg);
grad_h = conv2(k, gh);
grad = sqrt(grad_g.^2 + grad_h.^2);

[r, s] = size(grad);
thresh_grad = zeros(size(grad)); % Added
T = 80 / 255; % Change
for ii = 1:r
    for jj = 1:s

        if grad(ii, jj) < T
            thresh_grad(ii, jj) = 0;
        else 
            thresh_grad(ii, jj) = 1;
        end
    end
end

figure()
subplot(121); imshow(c);
subplot(122); imshow(thresh_grad);
```

Comment: I don't use the Image Processing Toolbox a whole lot (or any at all actually), I find it shocking that `imnoise` would clip double input to the [0,1] range. That's just asking for users to complain! :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo I only noticed this as I was debugging each variable in the code. I noticed the clipping when I displayed the image before and after `imnoise`. A bit ridiculous I know!

Comment: I have already solved it out.

Thank you everyone for your help and sorry for my late answer!